# Do I need to tie every ground pins of esp32 wroom 32 to the ground

Tags: pcb, ground, grounding, ground-loop

Which is the proper way of grounding for the module

To avoid the ground loop I think fig. A is the best.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: if there's some difference between A, B, C, D and E, it might be nice to point out what you think it is.

Comment: The short answer is yes.

Comment: What is the difference between the images?

Comment: Please look carefully on each ground pin on each image not every ground pins are connected to the ground on each image some images are all ground connected some images are not.

Comment: @WoraK - please use reasonable color settings if you want people to see whatever your point is.

Comment: Typically you would connect *all* of the grounds to a pour running under the module except for in antenna keepout areas, and likely for thermal relief around the pods.  However, the situation with a *module* is not necessarily the same as a bare chip - with a bare chip connecting all of the grounds is a functional requirement, with a module it might not be (depends what the module designer did) but it can still be important to creating a quiet design.

Comment: We don't even know what pins are ground.  Aside from C, all the others look alike.

Comment: there are via-in-pad differences across pictures

Answer (score 1):

I think also A is better in order to avoid other signals return gnd path going through your module. But up until now I'm using "C" image and I've not anticipated any kind of problems.

Comment: I also seen many dev board use Fig. C